# How to select a row using a text in dynamic web table using selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my application my projects list grows dynamically in a table. I need to select a project using its name. Select button is in 2nd column and the project name is in 3rd column. How to open the project using its name?

```html
<table class="ui celled definition sortable striped compact table" xpath="1">
<thead class="full-width">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="9">
   <div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" class="ui search selection dropdown per-page">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" class="search" tabindex="0" type="text" value=""/>
   </div>
   <a href="/project-setup">
    <button class="ui orange big circular icon right floated button">
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="plus icon"/>
    </button>
   </a>
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="select-delete-check-box">
   <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
    <input class="hidden" id="selectAll" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""/>
    <label for="selectAll"/>
   </div>
  </th>
  <th> Open </th>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Owner</th>
  <th>Members</th>
  <th>Created At</th>
  <th>Last Updated</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="select-delete-check-box">
   <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
    <input class="hidden" id="5e992e2b14d2d67c91eb51c9" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""/>
    <label for="5e992e2b14d2d67c91eb51c9"/>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td class="collapsing">
   <a href="/project-setup?id=5e992e2b14d2d67c91eb51c9">
    <button class="ui green big circular icon right floated button">
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="pencil icon"/>
    </button>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class="step">
    <div class="content">
     <div class="title" style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;">A</div>
     <div class="description">
      <span>
       <i aria-hidden="true" class="blue globe icon"/>3,4</span>
      <br>
       <span>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="red map marker alternate icon"/> Poland</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>abc@abc.com</td>
   <td/>
   <td>17/04/2010, 09:48:51</td>
   <td>17/04/2010, 09:48:51</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="select-delete-check-box">
    <div class="ui fitted checkbox">
     <input class="hidden" id="5e97f0a0adba5850643c7202" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value=""/>
     <label for="5e97f0a0adba5850643c7202"/>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="collapsing">
    <a href="/project-setup?id=52">
     <button class="ui green big circular icon right floated button">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="pencil icon"/>
     </button>
    </a>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div class="step">
     <div class="content">
      <div class="title" style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;">B</div>
      <div class="description">
       <span>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="blue globe icon"/> 1,2</span>
       <br>
        <span>
         <i aria-hidden="true" class="red map marker alternate icon"/> Tamil Nadu, India</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
    <td>abc@abc.com</td>
    <td/>
    <td>16/04/2010, 11:14:00</td>
    <td>16/04/2010, 17:08:01</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: you can first grab the row of the desired project(3rd column) and then click on the button(2nd column) of that particular row. You can try the code i  provided in the answer.

Comment: Did the code helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
table.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='title' and contains(text(),'A')]/ancestor::td[1]/parent::tr/td[2]/a/button")).click();
```

Comment: Please you be kind enough to upvote and tick the answer as it was the solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry for the late tick.